# UDP - Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

Basically, I have a graphical swing application. I need to use UDP to send and receive data, but I don't want any receive(packet) calls in the application's code. I decided to run the receiving end of the program on a separate thread. The thread has an int field that gets updated to the value from incoming packets. How would I get the value of this field from the thread. Can I just call the get method for the field, or do I have to interrupt the thread first?

Comment: you can call the get method, just be aware that you are calling from a different thread meaning that the field can be updated while reading, so you might ending reading an older value then current. You can use volatile on the int filed to make sure there isn't any JVM optimisations on the field resulting on getting a cached value.

Comment: Okay, so the thread is working as intended, but as soon as I call its start() method, the parent thread hangs. Is it because I'm using a while(true) loop? Do I need to have the thread yield before the parent thread can run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the GUI thread can read the int getter safely (assuming appropriate synchronization or volatile variable), consider taking the time to use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) as it will make your app more responsive.  Basically you replace your custom thread with a SwingWorker object.  The code you now have in `run()` goes in `SwingWorker.doInBackground()`.

You start the worker and the `doInBackground` code executes in a separate thread.  Presumably this is a UDP receive loop.  When your loop receives an new int, you call `publish` (still in the background thread).  This will cause another SwingWorker method `process` (which you have overridden with some custom code) to be called in the event thread.  Here you can safely update your GUI because you are running in the event thread.

This eliminates the need to create timers to poll getter of the UDP thread.  The UI is more responsive because the receive -> publish -> process sequence is pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a synchronized getter method on the incoming packet count field of your packet reciever thread class.

See this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) for a quick tutorial on the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You have just 1 objective here. UI should not wait and hang for data on the network. You need a LinkedList (not a ArrayList), a dataJustArrived method, that notifies your LinkedList object. A thread that is running in a while (true), and waiting on LinkedList.

dataJustArrived, add's the data object to the linked list and notifies the wait. The wait unlocks, and checks if linkedList.lenght > 0, and removes (not GETS's, but removes) the data from the list and processes the UI.

Important points

- the add and wait should be in synchronized (dataList) code blocks
- addLast and removeFirst
- remove, DO NOT use get
- LinkedList will work, ArrayList will not work (will be very costly operation)
- after wait unlocks, CHECK for dataList.length > 0
- before you wait, check if dataList.lenght > 0, why wait if there is data to process right ?

  ```
  public synchronized void dataJustArrived(Object data) {
      synchronized (dataList) {
      dataList.addLast(data);
      this.notify();
      }
  }

  public void run() {
      Object data ;
      while (true) {
          synchronized (this) {
               if (dataList.isEmpty()) {
                  try {
                     dataList.wait();
                  } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                     ignored.printStackTrace();
                  }
               }
               if (!dataList.isEmpty)
                   data = dataList.removeFirst();
               //
               // Process your UI here
               //
          }
      }
  }
  ```